# macOS 10.13 High Sierra: [NSGraphicsContext flushGraphics] on background thread has no effect

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, cocoa, appkit, macos-high-sierra

Up until macOS 10.12 the following code worked fine on a background thread:

```
[nsView lockFocusFocus];
... draw something ...
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] flushGraphics];
[nsView unlockFocus];
```

With 10.13 however, flushGraphics does not update the view's contents immediately anymore.

I understand that drawing from a background thread is now discouraged, but this should not imply it's no longer possible. In fact, everything in ... draw something ... still goes to the view's backing store. Once drawRect: is called next time on the main UI thread, the view is refreshed with all content properly in place.

How can this be made to happen immediately? Is there a way to make changes to the view immediately visible?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that with macOS 10.13, if **drawRect:** doesn't actually draw anything within the scope of that method, the view's display will not refresh, even if its backing store was modified.

So if you want to flush pending changes to screen, the trick is to make AppKit *think* something was drawn, by drawing at least a small invisible rectangle:

```
- (void) drawRect: (NSRect)rect
{
    if (drawRectWasRequestedByRefresh) {
       // flush pending changes drawn on background thread
       [[NSColor clearColor] set];
       [NSBezierPath strokeRect: NSMakeRect(0,0,1,1)];
       drawRectWasRequestedByRefresh = NO;
    } else {
       // draw your view's regular contents here
    }
}
```

To trigger that refresh from a background thread, use this hack:

```
- (void) refresh
{
    drawRectWasRequestedByRefresh = YES;
    [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
}
```

This is certainly a dirty hack that will only be needed for apps that require immediate drawing from a background thread (for whatever reason). If anyone knows a better solution, I'll be happy to hear about it!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that with a recent macOS update to High Sierra, possibly 10.13.4, this issue has disappeared. So flushGraphics does now flush changes to screen as it did before.